# Regular Expression Filter for values in brackets

Tags: regex

I've been trying to get the correct filter for:

```
{0}{1/2}{R/G}{X}{Y}{Z}{R}{R}
```

I've tried this on rubular.com (http://rubular.com/r/niCiKoUfmN):

```
\{([0-Z])\}
```

I get:

```
{0}{X}{Y}{Z}{R}{R}
```

But I do not get:

```
{1/2}{R/G}
```

How can I write the regular expression so it gets all of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radical way consists to use a negated character class with the character you want to avoid:

```
\{([^}]*)\}
```

`[^}]` means all characters except `}`

`*` means zero or more times

Answer (score 4):

```
\{(\w)(?:\/(\w))?\}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/qlkCw_qlM7HuKx8P)

Comment: `\w` matches digits as well as letters, so the `\d` is redundant.  Also, inside a character class `|` does not mean "or" like it does elsewhere, it just matches a literal pipe character.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the slash sign (/) in your group. Further, you have to add an quantificator to tell the parser, more characters in brackets are allowed:

```
\{([0-Z/]+)\}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by adding an optional `/[0-Z]`

Which will give you:

```
\{([0-Z](\/[0-Z])?)\}
```

Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/3D0VPCaJX7

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
\{[0-Z\/]+\}
```

You don't need the parentheses unless you're wanting to use a subset of the match for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include 0 or more inclusions of the `/` clause.

***[`Debuggex Demo`](http://www.debuggex.com/r/9A-EoXFzDnE-v7fj/0)***

```
\{([0-Z][\/0-Z]*)\}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/AGmCSVHP0aR9D2y6)

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/86jX9/)*** in javascript